# I would like to not expose some of details in plain HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my application I want to assign some PHP values to javascript variable. So I used to following code

```
<?php echo $my_var="This is my php value"; ?>
<script>    
var my_js_var = "<?php echo $my_var; ?>";
</script>
```

But the problem is I want to hide the details from HTML source view. Now the details will display in HTML view source like

```
var my_js_var = "This is my php value";
```

How can I hide this type of details from HTML source ?

Comment: The best you can do is obfuscate it.

Comment: If you send data to the client, it's sent, by definition. The best for you seem to be some server-side processing and then only send to client safe data.

Comment: If you just want to hide the data from the HTML source, you'll need to fetch this variable's value using `AJAX`

Comment: @Tzar I need this at the time of initialize the application and need it entire application and till the end the application

Comment: @Tzar - that won't prevent someone from seeing it. That just delays it.

Comment: Well ofcourse it won't prevent it. But if the variable is coming from AJAX, it wont show up in the html source code.
@Elby you can call AJAX at the time of initialization.

Comment: @Tzar I tried Ajax but due to the ajax request delay it not working properly :(

Comment: its still visible in ajax if you inspect the network requests.

Comment: What are you actually trying to prevent? What is the end goal of this obfuscation?

Comment: The answer to your question would depend on why you need to hide this data.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to hash/encrypt it for use in the client and then verify the hash on the server size when the request is processed.